# Does Matlab support function-objects?

Tags: matlab, function-object

Trying to figure out if I have access to function object programming techniques for use in our Matlab scripts. This would be analogous to [.NET's Func type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx), or [Python's function objects](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/function.html). Does Matlab give functions first class object status?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab does have [function handles](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html) which can be passed to other functions. As one example, the function [fzero](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) will find the zero-crossing of the function you give as its first argument. Function handles can be stored in variables, cell-arrays or structs. Matlab also has [anonymous functions](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), which are similar to Python's lambda expressions. So it seems that functions in Matlab have all the properties to be considered [first class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function).

Some random examples:

```
>> sq = @(x) x^2 - 2
sq = 
    @(x)x^2-2

>> fzero(sq, 1)
ans =
    1.4142

>> class(sq)
ans =
function_handle

>> functions = {@(x) 2 * x, @(y) 3 * y, @exp}
functions = 
    @(x)2*x    @(y)3*y    @exp

>> functions{2}(10)
ans =
    30

>> functions{3}(1)
ans =
    2.7183
```

Comment: Sweet, its always synonym chasing when crossing languages. Thanks

Comment: Strictly speaking it isn't a synonym.  `MATLAB`'s handles are fundamentally different than function objects and function types.  They are really integers that are used to refer to a particular function or data elsewhere.  So they are a little closer to pointers than they are to function objects, although they aren't the same as pointers either since you can't do stuff like pointer arithmetic on them.

Comment: @TheBlackCat those are implementation details. Matlab is not a language with a clean object oriented design, so for sure function handles are not implemented in a purist way. But they can be used for all the standard applications seen in other languages, so effectively, they behave like first class objects.